# Installing PyInstaller on Mac

Tags: python, bash, pyinstaller

I have not seen this issue in my google searches.  I am trying to install PyInstaller on my work Mac which I do not have administrative access.

```
    $ pip install --user pyinstaller
    Collecting pyinstaller
    Requirement already satisfied: dis3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyinstaller)
    Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyinstaller)
    Requirement already satisfied: macholib>=1.8 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyinstaller)
    Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2017.8.1 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyinstaller)
    Requirement already satisfied: altgraph>=0.15 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from macholib>=1.8->pyinstaller)
    Requirement already satisfied: future in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pefile>=2017.8.1->pyinstaller)
    Installing collected packages: pyinstaller
    Successfully installed pyinstaller-3.3.1
```

The install seems successful, however...

```
    $ pyinstaller
    -bash: pyinstaller: command not found
```

I checked my PATH

```
    $ echo $PATH
    /usr/local/git/current/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/jc/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to install the tar.gz file from here:

http://www.pyinstaller.org/downloads.html

Then it can be run from the extracted folder.

```
    $ python pyinstaller.py script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac pip installed the binary in `/Users/%Username%/Library/Python/2.7/bin`. If you add that to your PATH it should work.