# How do you install pyinstaller on Mac

Tags: python

I have python 3.7 and am trying to get pyinstaller but heard that the two are not compatible. I tried to download 3.4 but my computer will not allow me to get it. Is there a version of python that works on Mac and can install pyinstaller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing PyInstaller on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49303277/installing-pyinstaller-on-mac)

Comment: pip3 install pyinstaller

Answer (score 0):

Is you have `pip` installed on your MAC computer, try the following command to install `pyinstaller` from `pip` : `pip install pyinstaller`

Answer (score 0):

From doing a quick search, it is suggested to install it using either [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) or [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). Sadly this is as far I can help you since I don't own a Mac myself. You may find more info in the documentation of [Pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#installing-in-mac-os-x).